# How to convert the columns from a csvfile into an orderedDict python

Tags: python, csv, ordereddictionary

I have a csv file and i need the columns to be printed as OrderedDict

I am able to convert the rows into an ordereddict using 
`collections.OrderedDict((row[0], row[1:]) for row in r)` in python (2.7.5)

But when i try the same for columns i am getting '`cannot unpack more than one value`' error.

Is there any workaround?

```
        fileLocation = 'C:/test.csv'
        with open(fileLocation,'rb') as f:
            r = csv.reader(f)
            od = collections.OrderedDict((row[0], row[1:]) for row in r)
        print od
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of code and input data along with a full error traceback.

Answer (score 0):

try using this

```
od = collections.OrderedDict((row[0], row[1:]) for row in r if len(row)>1)
```

this might be you have `row` with only `one column`